# Using Func<TEntity, TType> in a Linq Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I'm trying to use generics to search on some Entities using search parameters defined in a int/string Dictionary. I have a search info class like:

```
 public class SearchInfo<TEntity, TComparer>{
     public Func<TEntity, TComparer> Search { get; set; }
     public Func<string, TComparer> ConvertValueToSearchType { get; set; }
 }
```

Say i'm searching on a Int64 my Search Info will be set up like:

```
var searchInfo = new SearchInfo<Entity, Int64>();
searchInfo.Search = new Func<Entity, Int64>(i => i.Child.Id);
searchInfo.ConvertValueToSearchType  = new Func<string, Int64>(s=>Int64.Parse(s));
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
items = items.Where(i=> searchInfo.Search(i) == searchInfo.ConvertValueToSearchType(dictionary.Value));
```

However I keep getting the exception

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: LINQ to entities will have no clue what to do with a `Func<...>`, always use `Expression<Func<...>>`

Comment: ...and even then, I don't think the EF provider will have any success in translating that sort of thing to SQL. You're either going to have to do this filtering in memory or come up with a different approach.